# barnyard2 dead but subsys locked - error

Tags: services, snort

I installed snort and barnyard. When I start the snort service and barnyard service, initially they work. After a while barnyard service give an error.
Initially:

```
[root@- snort]# service barnyard2 start
Starting Snort Output Processor (barnyard2):               [  OK  ]
[root@- snort]# service barnyard2 status
barnyard2 (pid 19835) is running...
[root@- snort]# service snortd status
snort (pid 19820) is running...
```

....

After a while:

```
[root@- snort]# service barnyard2 status
barnyard2 dead but subsys locked

[root@- subsys]# ps -A | grep barnyard2 
[root@- subsys]# ps -A | grep snort
20079 pts/1    00:00:00 snort
[root@- subsys]# service snortd status
snort (pid 20079) is running...
[root@- subsys]# service barnyard2 status
barnyard2 dead but subsys locked
```

What sould I do for fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this command

> ## tail -100 /var/log/messages

I see the error message and realized my mistake. I didn't give the correct connection informations for databases. When I fixed it, problem is disappered.